# Greedy operator result is differ in positive and negative lookahead?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm confused about the greedy operator on positive and negative look ahead.

script for **positive lookahead**

```
foreach (<DATA>){
$_ = m/AAA.+(?=BBB)/g;
print "$&\n";
} 
__DATA__
AAA 1121 BBB
AAA 443  CCC
AAA 4431 BBB
ABC 321  EACA
AAA 321  BBB
ACD 431 MAKN
AAA 751  ABC
```

It's output

```
AAA 1121 

AAA 4431 

AAA 321
```

**Negative Lookahead**

```
foreach (<DATA>){
$_ = m/AAA.+(?!BBB)/g; 
print "$&\n";
}
```

It's output

```
AAA 1121 BBB
AAA 443  CCC
AAA 4431 BBB

AAA 321  BBB

AAA 751  ABC
```

In the execution of the `negative lookahed` do not consider the `(?!BBB)`. Because I'm using the greedy operator preceding the `(?!BBB)`. In that case, postive look ahead greed operator considers the `(?=BBB)`. Which is why gives the different result?

I can easily achieve the OP by the code `$_ = m/AAA\s\d+(?!.+BBB)/g;`.

But i don't know what is the execution of my code?

Comment: @votedowner add comment

Comment: Using `/g` there makes no sense and can cause hard to debug errors.

Comment: Please avoid using `$&`. It slows down every single match operation without captures in your program.

Comment: @ikegami this is [not true anymore](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Performance-issues) as of Perl 5.20.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's consider the first example:

```
AAA 1121 BBB
\_/\_______/^
 |     |    |
 |     |    +--- this (the empty string right there) satisfies (?!BBB)
 |     |
 |     +-------- matched by .+
 |     
 +-------------- matched by AAA
```

This is because the greedy `.+` consumes `1121 BBB` **including** the `BBB`. After it has consumed the rest of the line, `(?!BBB)` is checked against the remaining empty string. And this empty string satisfies `(?!BBB)` since it's not followed by `BBB`?

---

### Negative lookahead

The algorithm executes like the following. `^` is the *current position* (there's a current position in the string and a current position in the pattern <sub>*(kind of)*</sub>).

1. Initial state:

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?!BBB)
   ^                     ^
   ```
2. Match `AAA`

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?!BBB)
      ^                     ^
   ```
3. Match `.+`

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?!BBB)
               ^              ^
   ```
4. Check `(?!BBB)`

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?!BBB)
               ^                     ^
   ```
5. No `BBB` match at this position => Success!

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB
   \__________/
   ```

---

### Positive lookahead

Now, let's see why *exactly* `AAA.+(?=BBB)` yields a match:

1. Initial state:

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?=BBB)
   ^                     ^
   ```
2. Match `AAA`

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?=BBB)
      ^                     ^
   ```
3. Match `.+`

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?=BBB)
               ^              ^
   ```
4. Check `(?=BBB)`

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?=BBB)
               ^              ^
   ```

   No `BBB` match at this position => Backtrack (consume one less char by `.+`)
5. Check `(?=BBB)`

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?=BBB)
              ^               ^
   ```

   No `BBB` match at this position => Backtrack (consume one less char by `.+`)
6. Check `(?=BBB)`

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?=BBB)
             ^                ^
   ```

   No `BBB` match at this position => Backtrack (consume one less char by `.+`)
7. Check `(?=BBB)`

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB          AAA.+(?=BBB)
            ^                        ^
   ```
8. We do have a `BBB` match at this position => Success!

   ```
   AAA 1121 BBB
   \_______/
   ```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in how it works in your two cases, and `.+` is greedy in both of your cases.

When matching `AAA.+(?=BBB)` against `AAA 1121 BBB`, the most `.+` can match starting after `AAA` is `<spc>1121<spc>`. Anything longer will cause `(?=BBB)` to fail.

When matching `AAA.+(?!BBB)` against `AAA 1121 BBB`, the most `.+` can match starting after `AAA` is `<spc>1121<spc>BBB`. Being the rest of the string, it can't possibly match anything longer.

Note that the end of the string isn't followed by `BBB`, so `(?!BBB)` matches at the end of the string.

---

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`.

I'd go with

```
say $1 if /^(AAA\s+\S+)\s+(?:(?!BBB)\s)*\z/;
```

On second thought, I'd go with

```
my @F = split;
say "$F[0] $F[1]" if $F[0] eq 'AAA' && $F[2] ne 'BBB';
```